# Circular shift an array R

Tags: arrays, r

I'm trying to circularly shift an N dimensional array in R. Here is an example from the `pracma` package of shifting a 2D matrix `a`:

```
if (is.matrix(a) && length(sz) == 2) {
    n <- nrow(a); m <- ncol(a)
    s1 <- sz[1] %% n
    s2 <- sz[2] %% m
    a <- a[(1:n-s1-1) %% n + 1, (1:m-s2-1) %% m + 1]
}
```

I'm trying to shift an N dimensional, array, and here's what I've come up with so far:

```
else if (is.array(a) && length(sz) > 2) {
    n <- dim(a)
    l <- length(n)
    for (i in 1:l) {
      s <- sz[i] %% n[i]
      #????
    }
```

The idea I was thinking of would be to circularly shift each dimension in the for loop separately. But I can't figure out if there is a way to do that, because the vector/matrix type code (where the dimensions are given in advance) won't work in this situation...

To be more specific, you have to explicitly index each dimension in the pracma code, but if you don't know how many dimensions, this would seem impossible. (Or, more likely, I just don't know how)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with the following approach:

```
# using map2 from purrr for simplicity, though you could also use lapply
library(purrr)

circshift_any <- function(a, sz) {
  indexers <- map2(dim(a), sz, function(len, s) (1:len - s - 1) %% len + 1)
  indexing_matrix <- as.matrix(do.call(expand.grid, indexers))

  array(a[indexing_matrix], dim(a))
}
```

This uses two tricks:

1. You can index a matrix with another matrix, not just with comma-separated vectors (e.g. you can do `as.matrix(mtcars)[cbind(1:3, 2:4)]`. It will turn it into a vector, but you can return it to an array with the same dimensions.
2. You can use `expand.grid` to create all combinations of several vectors. By giving it the index vectors you wanted, you can have each of those repeat appropriately.

You can confirm this works on a 2d matrix by comparing it to pracma's output:

```
a <- array(1:100, c(5, 20))

identical(pracma::circshift(a, c(3, 6)), circshift_any(a, c(3, 6)))
identical(pracma::circshift(a, c(23, 19)), circshift_any(a, c(23, 19)))
```